# Array in Pinia becomes proxy object. How can I use it with include() in a vue 3 template

Tags: vuejs3, nuxtjs3, pinia

I have an this in my pinia store:

```
mainNavigation: [
    {
    "_uid": "9acd58dd-a9de-4de1-bc2b-3e781cc42a59",
    "title": "Alla Produkter",
    "design": ["sale"],
    "divider": false,
    "component": "NestableNav",
    "permission": "all",
    "mobileButton": "Visa alla produkter",
    "desktopDesign": ["menuicon"],
  },
  // more objects
]
```

When i try to use them in Vue, both in `setup` and in the template;
`item.desktopDesign.includes('menuicon')` I get an error 500

If I do a `typeof` it says it's an object, a proxy object. With 0 as key.

I've tried `.value` but it doesn't work in code and shouldn't be necessary in the template.

Thanks

Comment: Could you re-produce your problem on https://stackblitz.com/?

Comment: a reproducible example in a sandbox would be good, or please at least paste code snippets showing how you're defining/using the store and your store's state within your component

Answer (score 0):

One way to fix this is by getting back the original array from vue created proxy using `toRaw()`

In your case, it will be like the following:

```
import { toRaw } from "vue";

const desktopDesign = toRaw(item.desktopDesign);
return desktopDesign.includes('menuicon')
```